# Change UI font-size in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, font-size, text-editor

Im using the [material-UI theme](https://atom.io/themes/atom-material-ui) in **Atom** (MacBook Pro, 2021). I wish to make some of the **UI text bigger**, ex the text on tabs, menus, buttons, welcome page and so on.
(note: I don't mean the text/code in the actual editor!).

For example, I wish to make the text of these menu options larger. (print-screen from Atom):

[image]

I can't find this option in neither the atom settings, nor the material settings. I've looked at the material less-files but I don't understand them. Searched google and SO but I haven't found a solution that works for me.

Please keep in mind that I am a **beginner** if you have an answer!

Comment: Firstly, welcome to SO! You may find this is better an operating-system level change of the DPI .. however, we're much more here to help with specific code questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ti7 This is not an OS question. Atom supports customizing pretty much any part of its UI. And questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are explicitly [on-topic](/help/on-topic). Not all questions need to be debugging questions.

Comment: @wjandrea the original question was mighty light on details, but is much better now!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Atom comes with a [user stylesheet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks) that one can use to override almost all parts of the UI. For example, you can add the following to increase the font-size of all DOM nodes by 120% – except the text editor itself:

```css
html:not(atom-text-editor) {
    font-size: 120% !important;
}
```

If you want to make more granular changes, you will need to use more specific CSS selectors. Fortunately, you can use Atom's built-in [developer tools](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#check-font-rendering-issues) to inspect the selectors of the editor.

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting in the Theme preferences - see my screenshots to locate the font size setting.

[image]

[image]